# What is weights in perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, perceptron

I am just diving into machine learning and started with learning artificial neural networks. So on learning about perceptron I stucked on wording "weights".
Is it rate of how much input item matched?
Please explain me what is weights in perceptron.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Using this picture I found online, you can see that the perceptron creates $y$ which is just the weighted sum of the inputs multiplied by an activation function (in the image it's a step function). So the weights are just scalar values that you multiple each input by before adding them and applying the nonlinear activation function i.e. $w_1$ and $w_2$ in the image.

So putting it all together, if we have inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$ which produce a known output $y$ then a perceptron using activation function $A$ can be written as

$$y' = \sum{A(x_i * w_i)}$$

The values of these weights are what get trained in the perceptron in such a way as to minimise some error metric between $y$ and $y'$

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have two nodes in a perceptron: node `A` and node `B`. These nodes are connected: `A` projects a connection to `B`:

```
A -------------> B
```

So let's say `A` has an activation value of `0.5`. The weight determines how much that value is changed before it gets to `B`. So let's say the weight is `4.`

```
        x4
A -------------> B
0.5              ?
```

So basically, to calculate how much `B` gets from `A`, we multiply the value of `A` with its corresponding weight: `0.5 x 4 = 2`.

```
        x4
A -------------> B
0.5              2
```

So `B` gets a value of `2` from `A` :)